# How to map doc_type fields if doc_type is a class

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping

My question is related to elastic search using python
I know that we can do mappings 
by this way

```
esearch.indices.create(index='test-index', body = request_body,ignore=400)
```

where

```
request_body =
{"mappings": 
{"TestDocType":
{
"properties":
{
"id":{"type":"integer"}, 
 "name":{"type":"text"}, 
 "description":{"type":"text"}
}
}

}
}
```

but I want to get the mappings from a class like this

```
import json
from elasticsearch_dsl import String, Integer, Float, Date, Boolean
from profile_doc import ProfileDocType


class TestDocType(ProfileDocType):

    id = Integer()

    title = String()

    description = String()

    class Meta: 
        index = "Test-index"



    def serialize(self, prod):
        return {
            'id': prod.id,
            'name': prod.title,
            'description': prod.description,
        }
```

where  ProfileDocType is

```
from datetime import datetime

from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType

    class ProfileDocType(DocType):

        def serialize(self, profile):

            profile["updated_on"] = str(datetime.now())

            return profile
```

I want to get the mapping of TestDocType class and add it to the index 
how this could be done ? 
if u don't understand what I mean please check automapping in c# elastic search https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html

yout help will be greatly appreciated : )

Comment: You might want to read the [style-guide](https://www.python.org/devm/peps/pep-0008/) - your python (ProfileDocType ) code has `IndexError` and des not use 4 spaces for indentation which makes it hard to read. Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: edited thnx @PatrickArtner